# Python: Capture image from camera on press space key using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the code below to capure frames from the camera when space key is pressed and save the frame to file. This code works OK.

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://10.0.0.90:554/?chID=1&streamType=main&linkType=tcp")

cv2.namedWindow("test")

img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)
    if not ret:
        break
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Escape hit, closing...")
        break
    elif k%256 == 32:
        # SPACE pressed
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I need your help to edit this code and create new loop where every half second 2 last frames will blink so I can

```
cv2.imshow('image', previous_frame)
time.sleep(0.5)
cv2.imshow('image', last_frame)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

So the task is when the programm starts show the first still frame (opencv_frame_0.png). When the space key pressed start flashing 2 images (opencv_frame_0 and opencv_frame_1) every 0.5 sec. When space key pressed again the images that will flash will be opencv_frame_1 and opencv_frame_2.

I am noob in python and opencv and need some help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you displaying the image you captured before checking the return value? You should check before you display it.

Comment: Why are you using `elif k%256 == 32:`? You don't need an `else` because you already returned and exited if the key was 27.